How can I set order item quantity when manually creating a new order and search by SKU?
I recently updated from Drupal Commerce 2.39 to 2.40. I just noticed that when I manually create an order, I can no longer search for order items by SKU or specify the item quantity. The order items field is using an autocomplete widget that allows me to search by product name, but not by SKU.
I don't often create orders manually. Whatever changed might be part of an earlier release than 2.40, but I don't see an obvious task in the release notes for recent releases.
Is it possible to add order items by SKU? How can I adjust the order item quantity?

This might be related: when I try to edit the order items view (admin/structure/views/view/commerce_order_item_table), I get an error: "Oops, something went wrong. Check your browser's developer console for more details." The developer console messages include this: ""\nAn AJAX HTTP error occurred.\nHTTP Result Code: 500\nDebugging information follows.\nPath: /admin/structure/views/view/commerce_order_item_table/preview/default\nStatusText: Internal Server Error\nResponseText: ""

The problem is with the widget used for the order items field. Changing it from "Autocomplete" to "Inline entity form - Complex" returned the order edit form to its familiar, expected functionality. After making that change I can now see an "Edit" button for each order item that lets me adjust the quantity and search by product variation. I can also set the quantity and override the unit price when adding a new order item.
